# Two activities with different colored status bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, statusbar

I have two activities, first activity should have a black status bar and second activity should have white action bar.
So how can I do that?

I want to change status bar color but the same color should not be applied to all activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to change the color of the status bar:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
activity.getWindow()ow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.custom_color));
```

Or create a custom theme with other colors and set it in second activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setTheme(android.R.style.CustomThemeWithOtherColors);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing status bar color, try below method

```
public static void statusBarColor(Context context, int color) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(
                darkenColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(activity, color)));
    }

}
```

**Method call**

```
statusBarColor(this,R.color.colorAccent);
```